# Setting environment variables for build in Visual Studio (2008)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, qt

I looked at some projects generated by the Qt plugin for VS and noticed that they use the environment variable QTDIR to refer for example to the Qt header files. However I failed to figure out where this variable is set. I guess it must be somewhere in the project settings, however I could not find it. Also please note that I am referring to the environment variables required during the build, not the ones for debugging.

Answer (score 7):

On Windows there are two ways to set an environment variable like QTDIR: either permanently in `System Properties->Advanced->Environment Variables` or temporarily for a single cmd session by opening `cmd.exe` and executing `set QTDIR=/path/to/qt`; now when starting VS from that commandline (execute `devenv.exe`) it will use the QTDIR value just set. The second case you use mainly when you have multiple QT installations.

Apart from that, you can also use User Macros in VS Property sheets. From the build tools' point of view they are sort of equivalent to environment variables. Add a new property sheet to your project, double click on the new sheet, go to the `User Macros` page and click on `Add Macro`. Nice thing is you can share this property sheet amongst all your Qt projects.

Answer (score 2):

When you install Qt through the setup wizard (i.e. not manually), the installation process sets the system environment variable QTDIR. This is not a project-specific thing, it is set for your whole system. You can check that at the location stijn described.

Hint: You can press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd> to open the system properties dialog (where <kbd>Win</kbd> is the key between <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>)

Comment: I don't think it did this here, I installed the qtsdk automatically.

Comment: Yeah then the installer has set QTDIR for your system. If not, you should do it manually. Or if you want to use different Qt Versions for different projects, stijn pretty much described your options here

Comment: Well of cousre I already did it manually, but I thought there would be a VS option to do that only for the build..

Comment: Well if you have the add-in installed, you can define multiple Qt versions under Tools->Options->Qt, and if you click a project and hit [Alt]+[Enter], you can usually choose or set the Qt version there (It might be necessary to define it previously). That obviously applies always, not only for the current build.